# Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager - Change loaded image Size

Tags: media-library

The new media manager loads the FULL size images which is REALLY inefficient for a thumbnail. I'd like to replace it with a different size thumbnail that is also stored for each source image. Can't seem to find a way to do that either. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: You want to specify a different thumbnail size, or you want to have other image size options other than thumbnail, medium, full??, Make your question lil more clear.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. the grid of images that load in the new media browser display actually load in the full size images. (also defaults to ALL MEDIA ITEMS) which is incredibly inefficient. I want to try to force wordpress to instead load a different size image in each box of that grid. So it loads faster.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I couldn't work out why some images I uploaded early in my development process where showing thumbnails and others uploaded later were showing the full image constrained to 120px wide.

Finally realised it was because I disabled the Medium image size by setting both width and height to 0. It obviously uses the Medium image if available, and if not defaults to the full size. I just set Medium to 120x120 and regenerated the thumbnails (http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/‎) and now all good.

Comment: When you see a duplicate question do not paste the same answer, flag the question as duplicate instead.